# ActiveRecord Exclude Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to write a script to augment data in my table. However, if I run

```
Thing.all.each do |thing|
  ...
end
```

all the associations for each thing are loaded as well. Can I "exclude" the associations that I'm not using?

Comment: Are you looking for `Thing.where(....) do |thing| end` ?

Comment: Or if you want to exclude records, then `Thing.where.not(....) do |thing| end`

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Thing.all` will not eager load the objects associated to `Thing`.

If you however call any associated record inside the do-end block, that is the only time Rails will fetch the data from the database. An example would be something below.

```
Thing.all.each do |thing|
  # ...
  puts thing.animal.name
  # ...
end
```

If you do `Thing.all.includes(:animal)`, this is code that will eager load animal records.

Comment: Hmm, well then something is amiss because my associations certainly seem to be eager loading without prompting.

Comment: @BaileySmith, maybe you have a code inside the do-end block that calls the associated objects?

Comment: No, I am calling a column in Thing that has the same name as a column in Animal, but that shouldn't be the problem `Thing.all.each{|t| if t.text; puts t.id; end}`. Animal also has a `text` column.

Comment: Just noticed that there is a default scope including Animal. That's my problem.